# .each() setting attribute with weird behavior

Tags: jquery, each

Alright, I'm looping through an "row" of divs with the `JQuery.each()` function. And when i'm looping through them, i setup some attributes and alter some text.

It all works very well, except for the first div. There the param's aren't set properly.

[Here's an JSFiddle with the working code](http://jsfiddle.net/Q92na/)

The HTML could look like this ( it's dynamically generated )

```
<div dir="rl" id="row_1" class="obstacle cv_row_rl rows ui-draggable ui-droppable" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 50px;">
    <div class="cv_chest" id="chest_1_12" chest_height="1"><span class="stapel_counter">12</span><span class="stapel_height">1</span>

    </div>
    <div class="cv_chest" id="chest_1_11" chest_height="1"><span class="stapel_counter">11</span><span class="stapel_height">1</span>

    </div>
    <div class="cv_chest" id="chest_1_10" chest_height="1"><span class="stapel_counter">10</span><span class="stapel_height">1</span>

    </div>
    <div class="cv_chest" id="chest_1_9" chest_height="1"><span class="stapel_counter">9</span><span class="stapel_height">1</span>

    </div>
    <div class="cv_chest" id="chest_1_8" chest_height="1"><span class="stapel_counter">8</span><span class="stapel_height">1</span>

    </div>
    <div class="cv_chest" id="chest_1_7" chest_height="1"><span class="stapel_counter">7</span><span class="stapel_height">1</span>

    </div>
    <div class="cv_chest" id="chest_1_6" chest_height="1"><span class="stapel_counter">6</span><span class="stapel_height">1</span>

    </div>
    <div class="cv_chest" id="chest_1_5" chest_height="1"><span class="stapel_counter">5</span><span class="stapel_height">1</span>


    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS looks like this (pulled out of an onclick event handler for better readability for you guys... ):

```
var chest_id = "chest_1_6";

function removeIt() {
    var parent_id = $('#' + chest_id).parent().attr('id');
    $("#" + chest_id).remove();

    var row = $("#" + parent_id);
    var dir = $(row).attr("dir");
    var length = $("#" + parent_id + " > div.cv_chest").length;
    var tmpCounter = 1;
    var chest_split = chest_id.split('_');
    var chest_base = chest_split[0] + "_" + chest_split[1] + "_";

    $("#" + parent_id + " > div.cv_chest").each(function (i, obj) {
        var chestId = $(obj).attr('id');
        log(length);
        log(chestId);
        log(chest_base + length);
        $("#" + chestId + " > .stapel_counter").html(length);
        $("#" + chestId).attr('id', chest_base + length);
        length--;
    });
}

function log(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

As you can see in the JSFiddle, is the chest properly removed, but the count isn't resetted right ( the count is the first span with the class `stapel_counter`.

So do you guys know what i did miss?

Let me know if you need any more information...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are changing the id of the elements in the loop. After the first iteration you have changed the id of the first element to `chest_1_11`, but the second element also has that id. When you try to change the second element you will change the first element instead. This will go on until you get to the gap of the removed element where you get an id that is not used by another element, and after that the elements are changed correctly.

Instead of getting the id of the element and then construct a selector using the id, just get the element itself. That solves your problem with accessing the elements with conflicting id:

```
function removeIt() {
  var row = $('#' + chest_id).parent();
  $("#" + chest_id).remove();

  var dir = row.attr("dir");
  var length = $("div.cv_chest", row).length;
  var tmpCounter = 1;
  var chest_split = chest_id.split('_');
  var chest_base = chest_split[0] + "_" + chest_split[1] + "_";

  $("div.cv_chest", row).each(function (i, obj) {
    var chest = $(obj);
    $(".stapel_counter", chest).html(length);
    chest.attr('id', chest_base + length);
    length--;
  });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q92na/2/

Comment: Haha, if you put it that way, it's bloody obvious... Thank you for pointing that out for me!